# How to make use of AWS amplify libraries without using the amplify CLI for IOS development

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

How to manually configure amplify without using amplify CLI in IOS development.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CocoaPods for that as well.

Reference: [AWS Amplify for iOS - Installation](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios#installation)

Comment: In the IOS SDK how can we configure the app without calling CLI? as shown [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/q/platform/ios)